# how to arrange vowels be arranged in even places given the following conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can the letters of the word RESULT be arranged so that the vowels appear in even places only?

options:

a) $0$  b) $48$ c) $120$ d) $144$

MyApproach:

RESULT has $2$ vowels and $4$ consonants.

$2$ vowels can be arranged in $3$ places in $3C2$ ways and the rest can be arranged in $4!$ ways.

Therefore $4!$ . $3C2$=$72$

> Can Anyone give me the hint if I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You took order into account for the consonants but not for the vowels. That's the missing factor $2$.

Answer (score 2):

and two vowels can be permutated in $2!$ ways. So multiply by $2!$